# Show image button as HTML

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, visual-studio, imagebutton

Is it possible to show asp:ImageButton as HTML?

Below is piece of code;

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<img src='Images/desc.gif' >";
```

which i need to replace with asp:imagebutton due to its postbackURL property (as it supports navigation)

Hence i have replaced my code as ;

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<asp:ImageButton id=imgtempasc runat=server ImageUrl=~/Images/tempasc.gif PostBackUrl=~/OT_Overview_Home.aspx >";
```

to show image button instead of image (as in code # 1) but Code # 2 doesn't work

thanks!

Comment: your question isn't very clear: you should support some information about the current and the wanted output.

Comment: the code given in the question would display an image in the gridview cell but with no Link to navigate to some other page. Thus i want an image button in place of current HTML button

Comment: you do not need an `Image` for that ... what you want is `Hyperlink` (as it has the property `ImageUrl`) - see my edit!

Comment: does hyperlink support an image?

Comment: see my edit of my answer (added a msdn-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand why you cannot use a `HyperLink` if you are modifying the Cell in your code? Especially if all you are doing is sending the user to another URL.

If you are simply sending the user from one URL to another, then will this not work

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<a href='http://yoururl'><img src='Images/desc.gif' ></a>";
```

If you require form data to be posted from your existing page to another page, then you will need to do what Andreas Niedermair has suggested and dynamically add the control to the GridView

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to modify your control-collection. therefore you will need to do it right, like this:

```
var imageButton = new ImageButton
{
    ImageUrl = "~/Images/asc.gif",
    PostBackUrl = "~/Home.aspx"
};
e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(imageButton);
```

Comment: I am using gridview. I just need an image button instead of HTML image as i need to navigate to some URL on click of image

Comment: Cannot use Hyperlink as it is not possible to replace with current HTML image. If it was,i would have replaced by ImageButton only

Comment: woho - your language isn't very clear either ... please: describe your problem clearly and support some demo-code for illustration! otherwise helping (or better: guessing) will not be very successful!

Comment: e.Row.Cells[0].Text = 
"<asp:ImageButton id=imgtempasc runat=server ImageUrl=~/Images/asc.gif PostBackUrl=~/Home.aspx >";

Comment: This is what i wish to add, but the image button is not visible in the grid's cell # 0

Comment: you should enhance your question and not add comments to my answer - as others won't read my answer and its comments ... nevertheless: your question will not clearer with this information! i'm still asking: "wtf? .. where is the problem?"

Comment: @Xorpower let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1862/discussion-between-andreas-niedermair-and-xor-power)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP:HyperLink!

Hyperlink Control has a ImageUrl property that you can use in order to set image for your link.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
 ID="myHyperLink" ImageUrl="~/foo.jpg" 
 NavigateUrl="~/YourUrl.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
```

You can do whatever you want with hyperlink.

Comment: i've added this fact minutes ago to my answer ... you should have read the op comments to this (`Cannot use Hyperlink as it is not possible to replace with current HTML image. If it was,i would have replaced by ImageButton only` - whatever that may mean)